# How to merge two arrays which are inside individual objects as property

Tags: javascript, lodash, higher-order-functions

I have two objects like this:

```
let obj1 = { slotIDs: ["5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15"] }
let obj2 = { slotIDs: ["5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15", "5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c"] }
```

I need to merge them inside a single array like this

```
let newObj = ["5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15", "5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c"]
```

I have tried using lodash union and map but no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**One line of code** solution:

```js
let obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15'] }
let obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

const result = [...new Set([...obj1.slotIDs, ...obj2.slotIDs])]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

With Vanilla JS you can iterate with `Array.flatMap()` and return the `slotIDs` to get an array of ids. To remove duplicates, create a Set from the array, and spread the Set back to an array:

```js
const obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15'] }
const obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

const result = [...new Set([obj1, obj2].flatMap(o => o.slotIDs))]

console.log(result)
```

With lodash you can iterate with `_.flatMap()` and take the `slotIDs` to get an array of ids. Use `_.uniq()` To remove duplicates:

```js
const obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15'] }
const obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

const result = _.uniq(_.flatMap([obj1, obj2], 'slotIDs'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>Try</s>

```
let newObj= []
for(const value in Object.assign(obj1,obj2)["slotIDs"])
newObj.push(Object.assign(obj1,obj2)["slotIDs"][value])
```

Edit- Here's a simpler or one-line version.

```
let newObj=Object.assign(obj1,obj2)["slotIDs"]
```

As @OriDrori Suggested, the above methods alters the obj1 itself and doesn't works well in similar questions where Obj1 has multiple key, value pair. Here's what you do to avoid that

```
let newObj=Array.from(new Set(obj1.slotIDs.concat(obj2.slotIDs)))
```

Quick Note- Use of `Array.from()` is optional.

Comment: @MianMuhammad I won't argue, It's just how you prefer it :-)

Comment: Your code override `obj1.slotIDs` with `obj2.slotIDs`, and doesn't merge the arrays, and gets only the unique values. Add another unique id to the `obj1.slotIDs`, and it will disappear in the result, or just change the order of objects in the assign to `obj2, obj1`, and check the result.

Comment: @OriDrori the solution was problem was Question specific and it's not the best solution, I agree.

Comment: I'll add a better solution too though :)

Comment: The code `Object.assign(obj1,obj2)["slotIDs"]` is not a solution. It does something else entirely.

Comment: @OriDrori not sure what you exactly mean by "not a solution". It produces the exact array. Either way, I've put a better solution.

Comment: It means that it doesn't merge the arrays and get the unique values, it just overrides the 1st object with the 2nd object (while mutating the 1st one btw). See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsdec5wm/) (look at the console). This time the result is the array of `obj2` since I've switched the order.

Comment: That's what i meant when i said, it was "Question specific". I know what it does and that is why I'd added a better answer.

Comment: @OriDrori the first solution is not as I was expecting, and Saurav IDs in both objects can be different each time, as I am fetching data from database.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.assign(obj1, obj2).slotIDs`

```js
const obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15'] }
const obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

const result = Object.assign(obj1, obj2).slotIDs

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your code override `obj1.slotIDs` with `obj2.slotIDs`, and doesn't merge the arrays, and gets only the unique values. Add another unique id to the `obj1.slotIDs`, and it will disappear in the result, or just change the order of objects in the assign to `obj2, obj1`, and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

```js
let obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e0301f353ee2a0546298f16'] }
let obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

let result = Array.from( new Set(obj1.slotIDs.concat(obj2.slotIDs)) )

console.log(result)
```

---

**Old answer:**

How about `{ ...obj1, ...obj2 }.slotIDs`?

```js
let obj1 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15'] }
let obj2 = { slotIDs: ['5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15', '5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c'] }

let result = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }.slotIDs

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wao, that's another simple solution Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If your object can have additional properties which hold array values and you would like to merge all of these into a unique array you can use `Object.entries()` with `.map()` and then a `Set` to remove the duplicates:

```js
const obj1 = { slotIDs: ["5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15"], itemIds: ["xyz123"] };
const obj2 = { slotIDs: ["5e0301f353ee2a0546298f15", "5e03050453ee2a0546298f1c"], itemids: ["xyz123", "abc123"] };

const res = [...new Set([obj1, obj2].map(Object.values).flat(2))];
console.log(res);
```